# phpbb3 facebook login

Tags: facebook, phpbb

I'm searching for facebook login plugin for phpbb3 , by login i mean, if you have facebook acount and you want to log in to the forum, you don't have to register, just to type your facebook info, or something similar to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple working plugin: [OAuthorize phpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=2165898)

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://phpbbjs.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5, its still in beta.

You register to the board via your details from facebook, except the password, you need to specify it (it shouldn't be the same as in facebook).